# Setting significance levels for multiple testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, multiple-comparisons

I have data from a number of data sets I am looking to find a correlation between measured volatiles. I have performed a t-test and have a p-value for each set of data. I now need to determine if I have a significant number of p<0.05. For example I have 40 sets with p<0.05 and 5 sets p>0.05, I now need to be able to say if this is significant, can you help?

Comment: First, correlation isn't measure by t-tests. Second, your general question is one of multiple comparisons. [Here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-comparisons) is a list of threads with that tag. Look around in there and see if you find an answer.

Comment: @PeterFlom serendipitously, for a binary exposure, the t-test is equivalent to a linear regression model for inference on a difference in means which is also asymptotically consistent with tests of Pearson correlation. This is an all-too familiar type of question with GWAS analyses. Agreed on the second point, though.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize that @AdamO. Even so, using a t-test and saying "correlation" is going to raise eyebrows.

Comment: @PeterFlom yes, OP would do very well to present his results as "tests of differences in mean volatility" which is a prespecified meaningful association measure for this analysis. Correlation may be too vague to actually mean anything to the audience, when raw differences actually have units and suggest something useful.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to review methods for handling multiple comparisons. In particular, [Bonferroni's Correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) is a very good place to start since it is an overly conservative method. I would be willing to wager many if not all of these so called significant findings would vanish under this correction. I suggest reviewing other posts under the "Multiple-Testing" tag if you wish to further explore alternative methods.

Comment: The whole question of multiple comparisons is vexed. It is arguable whether they are need at all; and people forget that correcting for them (esp. with Bonferroni) will lower power.

Comment: We are in agreement on this point. I always say, "Only a stupid man  gets frustrated when, on a fishing expedition, he only catches red herrings." Some level of compromise could be reached by incorporating what's called a clinically meaningful difference. For instance, in microarray analyses of SNPs and gene  expression, you might find "statistical significance" in RNA concentration differences with and without a SNP, but those differences would be too negligible to ever suggest a big response from gene therapy. Geneticists eventually ask the statistician, "So what?" which is a bad thing.